# Create JSON object (with array) in php

Tags: php, json

I tried to create JSON object witch contain an array. I want to get JSON via AJAX, orginaly:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data/events.json',
    type: 'GET',
})
```

But I change this to

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'data/events.php',
  type: 'GET',
})
```

JSON I need looks like this:

```
{
  "events": [
  {
    "month": "6",
    "day": "12",
    "year": "2016",
    "title": "Lorem ipsum",
    "description": "desc..."
  },
  {
    "month": "6",
    "day": "9",
    "year": "2016",
    "title": "Lorem ipsum",
    "description": "desc..."
  }
  ]
}
```

I've tried:

```
$events = array(
    "events" => array(
        array(
            "month"=> "6",
            "day"=> "12",
            "year"=> "2016",
            "title"=> "Lorem ipsum",
            "description"=> "desc.."
        ),
        array(
            "month"=> "6",
            "day"=> "9",
            "year"=> "2016",
            "title"=> "Lorem ipsum",
            "description"=> "desc..."
        )
    )
);

echo json_encode($events);
```

But this is not working. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the response you get in ajax?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that code does give you that JSON...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the accepted answer didn't explain, I'll provide some information. In your original example, you have a static `.json` file, which when served by the webserver, will automaticllay be served with the `application/json` content type. However, in your php example, the webserver will not serve the JSON content type.

jQuery will automatically parse the response JSON if it detects the JSON content type. This is why your php example doesn't do exactly the same as the original, even though the JSON content itself is the same.

As Neeraj suggests, you can force the content type by setting `dataType`. Alternatively you can send the JSON header in your php, which will replicate your original example. It's good practice to set the relevant content type, so I recommend doing this even if you are setting `dataType`.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($events);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your array is ok , but in ajax 
Try:

> dataType: 'json' : This will convert your response to json object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data/events.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: That was a problem. Thanks!